# How to hande forking logic in a script and maintain readability?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

What is the best way to have a script that changes its functionality based on an argument?
I mean I can do:

```
if [ "$param" == "1" ];  then  
# do code here  
else  
# do compeletely different code here  
fi
```

but what happens when the code gets arbitrary large?
I don't expect some OO approach just some nice approach to keep the script clean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called "branching", not "forking".

You may divide the script up in functions, or write totally separate sub-scripts that you call from a main script.

Using functions:

```
handle_param_1 () {
    # do stuff for param == 1
}

handle_other_cases () {
    # do other stuff
}

# the above functions could be written in separate files
# that you source to import their definitions

case "$param" in
    1) handle_param_1 ;;
    *) handle_other_cases  ;;
esac
```

Using separate scripts:

```
case "$param" in
    1) somewhere/handle_param_1 ;;
    *) somewhere/handle_other_cases  ;;
esac
```

Comment: The subscripts are just to contain the functions and I would just `source` the subscripts?

Comment: @Jim If you want to do things in functions and you write the functions in separate files, then you would have to `source` those files.  When I mentioned subscripts, I was thinking about actual scripts though, that does the things you'd want to do.

Comment: So actual scripts containing functions and I source the scripts? That's what I understood. Why is there a way without functions?

Comment: @Jim "Why is there a way without functions"?? I don't understand. You may call scripts from a script.

Comment: I didn't know that. You mean execute a script itself?

Comment: @Jim Of course. You do it all the time from the command line. It works in a script as well. The shell script doesn't care if an external utility is a binary or a script.

Comment: I see and how can I pass the `"$param` in the scipt if it is e.g. just a boolean?

Comment: @Jim In your example, you would call a script if `$param` was 1. The script doesn't need to know that `$param` is 1 since it would not be called if it wasn't.  Scripts take command line arguments like any other command. These would be available in `$1`, `$2` etc. This would be described in any shell programming tutorial.

Comment: Not that's not the issue. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/397387/pass-some-indication-about-branching-logic-to-script