# Pass some indication about branching logic to script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I have a script that I want to branch out based on an argument.
Basically this argument is like a boolean.  But I would not want for the user to just type any garbage in the shell run command and interpret it as a true.
Or I would not want some string that I would need to take into account case sensitivity issues etc.
What I would like as an end result is:

```
some_script.sh arg1 arg2 arg3 --remove
```

So that:

```
PARAM1="$1"  
PARAM2="$2"  
PARAM3="$3"   
REMOVE=?--> what here   

if [ $REMOVE ]; then  
# remove some files  
fi
```

Comment: Is `some_script.sh` the script you need to call with sanitized arguments, or is it the main script? Please [edit] your question and add slightly more verbose examples of what you wish to happen (and not happen).

Comment: @Kusalananda:That is the main script

Comment: @Kusalananda: I updated post

Answer (score 4):

You can just check if the string `--remove` is in the positional parameters of your script.  bash version using the regex match operator `=~`:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $@ =~ --remove ]]; then
   echo "removing files"
fi

exit
```

POSIX version:

```
#!/bin/sh

for arg in "$@"; do
   if [ "$arg" = "--remove" ]; then
      echo "removing files"
   fi
done

exit
```

Answer (score 2):

While `$1` and friends work reasonably well for scripts with a fixed set of arguments, they don't really work all that well for scripts with dynamic arguments. For that, you want to use a loop and a case structure:

```
REMOVE=
for arg in "$@"; do
    case "$arg" in
        --remove)
            REMOVE=1
            ;;
        *)
            if [ ! -z "$REMOVE" ]; then
                # whatever you need to do to remove
            else
                # whatever you need to do if you do not want to remove
            fi
            ;;
    esac
done
```

This works well if you document that --remove only applies to the arguments that come after it; this would allow you to have a mixed command line, where the remove applies to some arguments but not to others:

```
script.sh arg1 arg2 --remove arg3
```

in the above example, `--remove` applies to arg3, but not to arg1 or arg2. You could add support for a `--noremove` command line option to your case structure too:

```
case "$arg" in
    --noremove)
        REMOVE=
        ;;
    --remove)
        # ... rest of the case remains as is from before
esac
```

which would then allow something like this:

```
script.sh --remove arg1 --noremove arg2 --remove arg3
```

in that example the `--remove` option applies to arg1 and arg3, but not to arg2.

Finally, if you want your `--remove` to apply to any argument, regardless of where it appears in the command line, then the easiest way to move forward is probably to use `getopt(1)`:

```
# reorder the command line so that option arguments come first
# and non-option arguments come second, separated by "--"
PARSED=$(getopt -o '' --long remove -n scriptname.sh -- "$@")
# overwrite $@ with the contents of the newly created $PARSED
# Note the quotes; they are essential
eval set -- "$PARSED"

REMOVE=

while true; do
    case "$1" in
        --remove)
            REMOVE=1
            shift
            ;;
        --)
            shift; break;
    esac
done

for arg in "$@"; do
    if [ ! -z "$REMOVE" ]; then
        # whatever you need to do to remove
    else
        # the other thing
    fi
done
```

The `-o` argument to `getopt` takes short options, so that you can use `-r` rather than `--remove`, if you prefer it. Getopt also has a few extra options for when you want options to (optionally) have arguments, etc, and allows for basic usage output for free, when users provide options that are not recognized by your script. There's an example that ships with GNU getopt that shows all the possibilities; on Debian (and derivatives) you can find it as `/usr/share/doc/util-linux/getopt-parse.bash`